# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, oop, attributeerror

The initial method TrendingUsersFullDeatils() works when not in a class and where self. count is substituted for a number.
However, when I created a class and pass through an integer I get an attribute error shown below:

```
tiktoks = tiktok_api.by_trending(count=self.count)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'
```

**CODE:**

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
import json

tiktok_api = TikTokApi.get_instance()
tiktok_data = []

class TikTokWebScraper():
    def __init__(self, count=0):
        self.count = int(count)
    
    def TrendingUsersFullDeatils(self):
        tiktoks = tiktok_api.by_trending(count=self.count)
        for tiktok in tiktoks:
            tiktok_data.append({"Username": tiktok["author"]["uniqueId"],
                                "Follower Count": tiktok["authorStats"]["followerCount"],
                                "Id": tiktok["author"]["id"],
                                "uniqueID": tiktok["author"]["uniqueId"],
                                "Nickname": tiktok["author"]["nickname"],
                                "Verfied Status": tiktok["author"]["verified"],
                                "Private": tiktok["author"]["privateAccount"],
                                "Following Count": tiktok["authorStats"]["followingCount"],
                                "Follower Count": tiktok["authorStats"]["followerCount"],
                                "Heart Count": tiktok["authorStats"]["heartCount"],
                                "Video Count": tiktok["authorStats"]["videoCount"]})
        f = open("tiktok.json", "w")
        j = json.dumps(tiktok_data, indent= 4)
        f.write(j)
        f.close()

TikTokWebScraper.TrendingUsersFullDeatils(10)
```

What amendments do I need to make to the class in order to pass through an integer to the method, as I have looked online and the solutions don't match mine for some reason.

***The following code will not function when imported into code as the necessary modules need to be installed and retrieved from a git repository.***

Comment: Seems you must have assigned an int the name `self`  somewhere.

Comment: Pass count to init, your method does not take arguments  other than self: `TikTokWebScraper(10).TrendingUsersFullDeatils()`

Comment: @Lesiak Thank You!!!!! I was passing an argument to a method that doesn't take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized your object (haven't called your **init** method). Also you're passing 10 as argument to TrendingUsersFullDeatils method, where the only argument is self. That's why it tries to get 'count' field in integer. Try this:

```
TikTokWebScraper(10).TrendingUsersFullDeatils()
```